Laravel 11 Breeze with React and Inertia - API Development
My WebApp needs a way to expose specific API endpoints so that a Windows Service can call. So, the WebApp needs both cookie-based authentication and token-based authentication. If I return a JSON response from the API mentioned above, I get an error from Inertia that it has to be an Inertia Response. How can I get around with this?
